# Set admob banner at the bottom of the screen/view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, admob

I'm trying to set an AdMob Banner for my app. In my Activity I've got a ListView, so I need to put the Banner on the bottom of it. The admob banner appears in the middle of the screen. How to fix it in the bottom of the screen?
Here is the code:

```
<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@drawable/sidebar_gradient"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/white_60_per_trans"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Can you post FULL xml.

Answer (score 3):

Seems the problem is because your code is not inside a RelativeLayout container, and the attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` will not work correctly, this code will work for you:

```
<RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


   <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/frame_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
       android:layout_width="270dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:background="@drawable/sidebar_gradient"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
       android:divider="@color/white_60_per_trans"
       android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />

   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       ads:adSize="BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
   </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not getting you wrong, you are switching fragments in FrameLayout, so you may try like this to show and hide ad view at bottom of the screen. Don't forget to change visibility of AdView.

```
    <RelativeLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

       <LinearLayout 
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/frame_container"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:weight="1" />

       <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
           android:id="@+id/adView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:visibility="gone"
           ads:adSize="BANNER"
           ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
       </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

       </LinearLayout>

       <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
           android:layout_width="270dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_gravity="start"
           android:background="@drawable/sidebar_gradient"
           android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
           android:divider="@color/white_60_per_trans"
           android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

I hope it will help!